# Changing the selected timestamp (with weekday) to Fr, Mo etc

Tags: php, mysql, time, weekday

I have the following code:

```
$meetings= $db->query("SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(meetings.time, '%W, %d.%c.%Y - %H:%i') AS time2 FROM meetings");
while ($row = $meetings->fetch_object()) {
    echo'
    <tr>
        <td class="td_contentbar">'.$row ->title.'</td>
        <td class="td_contentbar">'.$row ->time2.'</td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
```

And I want to get an output which shows me the time of that meeting, but the time has to be output like this:
***Fr, 06.07.2015 - 20:52*** (with Mo, Fr etc...)

How can I solve this?

Comment: mysql has no format character for two-char week names, so you're stuck doing it on your own `CONCAT(LEFT(date_format(meetings.time, '%W'), 2), DATE_FORMAT(', ....) etc....)`

Comment: w3fools is a crap site. go read the real documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format  and no, that's a THREE character date. OP wants 2 char...

Comment: Can I put something into the query like: If %w = 5 then  %w = Fr? I don't know how to write this.

Comment: yes, there's `if` and `case` in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(DATE_FORMAT(meetings.time, '%W'),2), DATE_FORMAT(meetings.time, ', %d.%c.%Y - %H:%i')) AS time FROM meetings
```

Comment: This outputs me an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object

Comment: check your while loop

    $row_termine_alle should be $row

remember to include the title column in your query as well